# ViewController covered up by NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My view is going under the navigation bar. Most of the view is showing, except the top part which is covered up by the Nav bar. How do I prevent that?

Comment: you navigation bar is opaque or translucent ?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: Add your `ViewController`'s top view's top layout to safeArea not to superView

Comment: whats the code?

Comment: @TylerRutt its related to Storyboard design if you use Storyboard. Or you need to add Constraint programmatically with the top safe area.

Comment: I add the nav bar in programatically, so I need to do It that way. I like the storyboard, but In this specific instance I need to do it programatically.

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/playing-it-safe-with-safe-area-layout-guide-b3f09bdc71fe

Comment: @TylerRutt please share your code for better explanation and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the anchor to safeAreaLayoutGuide like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
])
```

same thing for bottom if you have a tabbar:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Also, remember to set `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on "myView"

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false